# Unable to resolve Hostname for pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, hostname

I'm following the makezine tutorial [Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins and Python](http://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/)
and I get to the part "USING THE RPI.GPIO LIBRARY" but the next command `sudo python` won't work. I get error `unable to resolve host`.

I'm very new to `pi` and in general Linux. I'm also really bad at using the console. Help is greatly appreciated.

The whole error message is:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi
```

Comment: It is added in an edit

Comment: Did you by chance change your hostname? [This guy had the same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1772387)

Comment: It seemed to work. When I do sudo python now, I get no error message, but it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Okay, cool. Another longshot; does the python file have running code in it? (i.e. did you call `main()`)? Try running it without the `sudo` and see what happens.

Comment: I appreciate the help! The file has no code in it. I'm following the guide entirely. If I use just python, the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the console
2. Type in: `cd /home/pi`
3. Then type in: sudo nano myInputSketch.py
4. Copy the code below:

   ```
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
   GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

   print("Welcome! Press any button on your bread board. To quit this, press Ctrl + C")

   try:
       while True:
           GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.RISING)
           print("Button 1 Pressed")
           GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
           print("Button 1 Released")
           GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.FALLING)
           print("Button 2 Pressed")
           GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.RISING)
           print("Button 2 Released")
   except:
       print("Bye bye!")
       GPIO.cleanup()
   ```
5. Press **Crtl + X** then **Y** then hit ENTER
6. Type in: sudo python myInputSketch.py
7. Enjoy!